# stack parameters read from wrong memory address in the stack

Tags: c, gdb, stack, arm, corruption

I am trying to debug a process core dump on ARM architecture.

It is a telecom stack software written in C. The process is single-threaded.

Some debugging through gdb indicated that the stack parameters (local variables or function arguments) are being read from a memory location that is at a fixed offset (8 bytes) from the correct location.

Here is some debugging information:

```
(gdb) p localParam_p
$16 = (UInt8 *) 0xbe <Address 0xbe out of bounds>

(gdb) x /16wx &localParam_p
0x7ea5c774:     0x000000be      0x00000010      0x94dc788c     0x00000000
```

The correct (expected) value is 0x94dc788c which is stored at a memory location 0x7ea5c77c (third word in the output above)

Here is another example:

```
(gdb) p localParam2
$18 = 0

(gdb) x /16wx &localParam2
0x7ea5c770:     0x00000000      0x000000be      0x00000010     0x94dc788c
```

Expected value for addrLen is 0x10 (third word above).

I can see the same issue with other local variables across stack frames.

Kindly help!

Valgrind can not be used on this system.

The process has only crashed once in a duration of several days and the reproduction steps are as yet unknown.

Comment: What exactly should we help you with? Where's the code? We're not *espers*, you know.

Comment: I am looking for hints / direction that I should take to debug it further.

Comment: 8 bytes or 8 bits? But `p localParam_p` prints the value at address `0x7ea5c774` which is correct, right?. What do you mean by the pointer `localParam_p` should rather print value at the next byte of `0x7ea5c774`

Comment: If you want a hint, maybe you should look for a function called with wrong parameters. If your prototypes/includes are not done correctly, the compiler won't warn you. That's why you always put the prototype in a .h that you include in both the function .c and the caller .c.

Comment: 8 bytes. `p localParam_p` printing the value at address `0x7ea5c774` is incorrect. The correct value is stored at  `0x7ea5c77c`

Comment: Thanks @ElderBug. I'm not sure if I understood it completely - are you suggesting that if a function call doesn't match the function prototype from the header file, the compiler won't complain?

Comment: Stack needs to be 8-byte aligned, so may be someone messing that up. Are you trying to combine pre-compiled object files or different tool chains?

Comment: @lalit_sam No, the compiler will complain if the call doesn't match the prototype, but won't complain if the prototype doesn't match the real function. If the prototype doesn't match the real function, the compiler will only complain if the prototype is included where the function is defined (i.e the compiler won't complain if the function can't "see" the wrong prototype).

Comment: Note that if you're using normal ARM calling conventions function arguments should mostly be passed in registers rather than on the stack. Is the code pulling any dirty tricks that assume otherwise?

Comment: @Notlikethat You are right! Up to four arguments are being passed in registers. These have correct values. The ones on stack (and local variables) are corrupted (offset by 8 bytes). I am not sure if it is relevant but the last method in the call stack is an inline method and O2 optimization is being used.

Comment: Thanks @ElderBug. It is a good suggestion. I am reviewing the code from this perspective. Could it also be due to mismatched argument types that are otherwise (implicitly) convertible. e.g. short to int or vice-versa. I see atleast one instance where a 32-bit signed integer is being converted to a 16-bit unsigned short. Can something of this sort cause stack corruption?

Comment: @lalit_sam Conversions should not cause any problem. Even if it is implicit, all conversions are safe. Corruption may occur if the called prototype doesn't match the real function signature. Because the compiler will set/stack parameters according to the prototype, even if it doesn't match the real function.

Comment: @auselen - No, I am not doing anything of this sort.

Comment: your question is very incomplete to deduct something. try adding up some code segments or if you can't, try to create a simple piece of code reproducing the same problem.

Comment: @auselen Thanks for you comments. I understand your point. I can't share the actual code due to IPR issues. I tried to reproduce the issue in a test program but in vain. Nonetheless, I will keep trying.

Comment: @ElderBug This is interesting - I never thought about it before. I'll try to reproduce the problem you mentioned in a test program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reaction to this sort of thing is to suspect a compiler debuginfo bug.  It could also be a gdb bug.  If I had this problem, here is what I would do:

First, make sure I had a recent version of gdb; upgrading to the latest release if not.

If that didn't work, enable DWARF location disassembly:

```
maint set dwarf2 always-disassemble on
```

Then ask for the location of the variable in question:

```
info addr localParm2
```

This will dump a DWARF expression showing where gdb thinks the variable is located.  DWARF expressions use a simple stack machine language, you will have to dig into the DWARF standard and perhaps some GCC extension documentation (on the GCC wiki) to understand this.

If you are not using DWARF -- well, you should these days, and that's a good spot to start.

This is the spot where I would expect to find the bug.  And, if so, the only answer is that you need to fix the compiler, either by upgrading or by debugging the problem there.

It's also possible that the compiler output is correct and that you've found a gdb bug.  I think this is less likely, though, since the location expression code in gdb has been fairly well exercised.

It's also worth double-checking that the debuginfo matches the program you are debugging.  And, it may worth looking to see if the compiler you're using has any known bugs in this area.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Tromey. Are you saying that the process crash could be due to an entirely different reason and gdb result might be a red herring. I'll go ahead and try your suggestion anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to know why gdb was giving the wrong answers.  It's hard to say whether or not these problems are related to the crash.  But I would suspect not.